# Grid Not Filling Available Space with XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am very, very new to XAML.  I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and I'm in WPF having problems getting a grid's labels, textboxes, and checkboxes to fill the remaining white space when a form is maximized or resized.  The controls all get slightly larger, but then stop at about a 25-33% increase in size.  I have borders under each text box to make the textboxes stand out on the form.

I'm thinking that the answer may lie in putting grid.columdefinitions and rowdefinitions around each control and setting the height and width to '*' rather than just slapping them all in a large one-cell grid.  I apologize for the lengthy attributes, I was trying several solutions and using GUI.

```
    Grid x:Name="Form"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="500" Height="620" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" XPath="/data" IsAsynchronous="False">
            <x:XData>
                <data xmlns="">

                </data>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label Content="TEST PAGE 1" Margin="103,4,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="line1box" Height="18" Margin="313,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="37" TextAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" MaxLines="1" MaxLength="4" FontSize="10"/>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="313,17,0,0" Width="37" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Label Content="Line 1" Margin="350,3,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.233,0.493" FontSize="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Label Content="Line 2" Margin="350,21,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.233,0.493" FontSize="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="line2box" Margin="313,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="37" TextAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" MaxLines="1" MaxLength="4" FontSize="10" TabIndex="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="313,5,0,0" Width="37" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="check1" Content="check1" Margin="312,18,0,0" FontSize="9" TabIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="check2" Content="check2" Margin="361,18,0,0" FontSize="9" TabIndex="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Label Content="Line 3" Margin="0,31,0,0" FontSize="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="insured" Margin="56,33,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="265" BorderThickness="0" Height="25" AcceptsReturn="True" MaxLines="2" FontSize="10" TabIndex="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Height="1" Margin="56,45,0,0" Width="265" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Height="1" Margin="56,57,0,0" Width="265" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<Label Content="Line 4" Margin="269,34,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.233,0.493" FontSize="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="line4box" Margin="309,37,0,0" Width="107" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="9" MaxLines="2" TabIndex="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="309,49,0,0" Width="107" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Label Content="line5" Margin="261,48,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.233,0.493" FontSize="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="line5box" Margin="309,50,0,0" Width="107" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="9" MaxLines="2" TabIndex="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="309,63,0,0" Width="107" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just noticed the rendertransformorigins.  I was literally trying everything but I thought I reset that.  I guess that's the curse of a GUI interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main problem when using the Visual Studio designer to create XAML-based UIs rather than creating XAML by hand.

Basically, all your UI elements have Hardcoded, fixed positions defined by their margins, for example:

```
<Label .. Margin="350,21,0,0" ... />
```

which constrain their maximum size, rather than having relative positions determined by their parent container and stretching to the available space.

Please have a look at [WPF Layout Tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html) for introductory material on how to create XAML-based layouts in a proper fashion.

Comment: Addition - the rendertransformorigins, in all it hurts my eyes.